# CMake, VTK8 and Embarcaderos Clang compiler

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, c++builder

The current Embarcadero version of C++ Builder (10.2.3) ships with Clang 32 and 64 bit C/C++ compilers. The Clang version is claimed to be 3.3, (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Win32_Clang-enhanced_Compilers).

I'm looking into compiling VTK 8.0, and other libraries using these compilers and CMake.

However, the 'system' CMake file (Windows-Embarcadero.cmake) that ships with CMake is not configured for Clang, but the older bcc32 compiler.

Embarcadero suggest to copy their distributed "Windows-Embarcadero.cmake" file (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Using_CMake_with_C%2B%2B_Builder), to CMakes Modules/Platform folder, and overwrite the Windows-Embarcadero.cmake file that is shipped with CMake. I'm using CMake 3.10.

However, following Embarcaderos suggestions don't allow much to be compiled. **In addition to not working properly, the new .cmake file *breaks* support for the old bcc32 compiler(!).**

The first error when trying to configure VTK8 sources using CMake and the bcc32x (clang32) compiler is:

```
CMake Error at CMake/vtkModuleMacros.cmake:586 (target_compile_features):
target_compile_features no known features for CXX compiler

"Embarcadero"

version 7.30.36015.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMake/vtkModuleMacros.cmake:660 (vtk_add_library)
Common/Core/CMakeLists.txt:399 (vtk_module_library)
```

Digging into the CMake/vtkModuleMacros at line 586 shows where the error occurs:

```
  function(vtk_add_library name)
  add_library(${name} ${ARGN} ${headers})
  # We use compile features to specify that VTK requires C++11.
  # We request a series of C++11 features that will conform to VTK's
  # desired minimum requirements.
  # - cxx_override enforces Intel 14+, and GCC 4.7+
  # - cxx_nullptr as this a hard requirement for all compiler
  # CMake 3.8+ introduces the concept of meta language compiler features, and
  # also introduces the first compilers that are only meta language feature
  # aware. So if we have CMake 3.8+ we will also set the meta feature as
  # a private flag ( private so we don't force consumers to also use 3.8+ )
  if(NOT VTK_IGNORE_CMAKE_CXX11_CHECKS)
    target_compile_features(${name} PUBLIC cxx_nullptr cxx_override) **This is line 586** 
    if(NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 3.8)
      target_compile_features(${name} PRIVATE cxx_std_11)
    endif()
  endif()
  if(NOT ARGV1 STREQUAL OBJECT)
    vtk_target(${name})
  endif()
endfunction()
```

This does perhaps indicate that the CMake file that Embarcadero ships is not proper/complete. Embarcaderos CMake file looks like this:

```
# Distributed under the OSI-approved BSD 3-Clause License.  See accompanying
# file Copyright.txt or https://cmake.org/licensing for details.

set(_EMBT_CPP_PREPROCESSOR "cpp32")
set(EMBT_TARGET Windows)

if(CMAKE_BASE_NAME STREQUAL "bcc32x")
  set(BCC32X TRUE)
  set(_EMBT_CPP_PREPROCESSOR "cpp32x")
  set(CLANG_BASED TRUE)
endif()

if(CMAKE_BASE_NAME STREQUAL "bcc64")
  set(BCC64 TRUE)
  set(_EMBT_CPP_PREPROCESSOR "cpp64")
  set(CLANG_BASED TRUE)
endif()

if(CMAKE_BASE_NAME STREQUAL "bcc32c")
  set(BCC32C TRUE)
  set(_EMBT_CPP_PREPROCESSOR "cpp32c")
endif()

# This module is shared by multiple languages; use include blocker.
if(__WINDOWS_EMBARCADERO)
  return()
endif()

set(__WINDOWS_EMBARCADERO 1)
set(BORLAND 1)

if("${CMAKE_${_lang}_COMPILER_VERSION}" VERSION_LESS 6.30)
  # Borland target type flags (bcc32 -h -t):
  set(_tW "-tW")       # -tW  GUI App         (implies -U__CONSOLE__)
  set(_tC "-tWC")      # -tWC Console App     (implies -D__CONSOLE__=1)
  set(_tD "-tWD")      # -tWD Build a DLL     (implies -D__DLL__=1 -D_DLL=1)
  set(_tM "-tWM")      # -tWM Enable threads  (implies -D__MT__=1 -D_MT=1)
  set(_tR "-tWR -tW-") # -tWR Use DLL runtime (implies -D_RTLDLL, and '-tW' too!!)
  # Notes:
  #  - The flags affect linking so we pass them to the linker.
  #  - The flags affect preprocessing so we pass them to the compiler.
  #  - Since '-tWR' implies '-tW' we use '-tWR -tW-' instead.
  #  - Since '-tW-' disables '-tWD' we use '-tWR -tW- -tWD' for DLLs.
else()
  set(EMBARCADERO 1)
  set(_tC "-tC") # Target is a console application
  set(_tD "-tD") # Target is a shared library
  set(_tM "-tM") # Target is multi-threaded
  set(_tR "-tR") # Target uses the dynamic RTL
  set(_tW "-tW") # Target is a Windows application
  set(_tV "-tV") # Target is a VCL application
  set(_tJ "-tJ") # Target uses the Delphi Runtime
  set(_tF "-tF") # Target is a FMX application
  set(_tP "-tP") # Target creates a Package
  set(_tU "-tU") # Target creates a Unicode
endif()

# if build type is not provided set it to debug mode
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
  set (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE DEBUG CACHE STRING "Choose the type of build, options are: DEBUG RELEASE RELWITHDEBINFO MINSIZEREL.")
endif()


# to get the latest version of Rad Studio Installed by passing _EMBT_SDK_DIR path.
macro(_embt_getbdsversion result curdir)
  file(GLOB children RELATIVE ${curdir} ${curdir}/*)
  set(dirlist "")
  foreach(child ${children})
    if(IS_DIRECTORY ${curdir}/${child})
      list(APPEND dirlist ${child})
    endif()
  endforeach()
  list(LENGTH dirlist dirlength)
  set(latest_dir_index ${dirlength})
  math(EXPR latest_dir_index "${latest_dir_index}-1")
  list (GET dirlist ${latest_dir_index} latest_dir)
  set(${result} ${latest_dir})
endmacro()

set(_EMBT_SDK_DIR "")

if(NOT "$ENV{APPDATA}" STREQUAL "")
  set(_EMBT_SDK_DIR "$ENV{APPDATA}\\Embarcadero\\BDS") #have to pick up by path from %APPDATA%
  string(REGEX REPLACE "\\\\" "/" _EMBT_SDK_DIR "${_EMBT_SDK_DIR}")
  file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "${_EMBT_SDK_DIR}" _EMBT_SDK_DIR)
endif()

if(EXISTS ${_EMBT_SDK_DIR})
  _embt_getbdsversion(LATESTVER ${_EMBT_SDK_DIR})
  get_filename_component(ROOTDIR "[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Embarcadero\\BDS\\${LATESTVER};RootDir]" ABSOLUTE CACHE)
  string(REGEX REPLACE "\\\\" "/" ROOTDIR ${ROOTDIR})
else()
  #if RAD Studio is not installed,
  find_path(BIN_DIR_PATH NAMES ${CMAKE_BASE_NAME}.exe)
  get_filename_component(ROOTDIR ${BIN_DIR_PATH} PATH)
endif()

include_directories(SYSTEM "${ROOTDIR}/include/windows/crtl")
include_directories(SYSTEM "${ROOTDIR}/include/windows/sdk")
include_directories(SYSTEM "${ROOTDIR}/include/windows/rtl")
include_directories(SYSTEM "${ROOTDIR}/include/dinkumware64")

if(BCC32X OR BCC32C)
  if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES ".*DEB.*")
    set(linker_Path1 "${ROOTDIR}/lib/win32c/debug")
    set(linker_Path2 "${ROOTDIR}/lib/win32/debug")
    set(linker_Path3 "${ROOTDIR}/lib/win32/debug/psdk")
    set(windows_LIBRARY "${windows_LIBRARY} -L \"${linker_Path1}\"")
    set(windows_LIBRARY "${windows_LIBRARY} -L \"${linker_Path2}\"")
    set(windows_LIBRARY "${windows_LIBRARY} -L \"${linker_Path3}\"")
  endif()
  set(linker_Path1 "${ROOTDIR}/lib/win32c/release")
  set(linker_Path2 "${ROOTDIR}/lib/win32/release")
  set(linker_Path3 "${ROOTDIR}/lib/win32/release/psdk")
  set(windows_LIBRARY "${windows_LIBRARY} -L \"${linker_Path1}\"")
  set(windows_LIBRARY "${windows_LIBRARY} -L \"${linker_Path2}\"")
  set(windows_LIBRARY "${windows_LIBRARY} -L \"${linker_Path3}\"")
endif()

if(CLANG_BASED)

  if(BCC32X)
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${ROOTDIR}/bin/bcc32x.exe)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${ROOTDIR}/bin/bcc32x.exe)
  endif()

  if(BCC64)
    if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES ".*DEB.*")
      set(linker_Path1 "${ROOTDIR}/lib/win64/debug")
      set(linker_Path2 "${ROOTDIR}/lib/win64/debug/psdk")
      set(windows_LIBRARY "${windows_LIBRARY} -L \"${linker_Path1}\"")
      set(windows_LIBRARY "${windows_LIBRARY} -L \"${linker_Path2}\"")
    endif()
    set(linker_Path1 "${ROOTDIR}/lib/win64/release")
    set(linker_Path2 "${ROOTDIR}/lib/win64/release/psdk")
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${ROOTDIR}/bin/bcc64.exe)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${ROOTDIR}/bin/bcc64.exe)
    set(windows_LIBRARY "${windows_LIBRARY} -L \"${linker_Path1}\"")
    set(windows_LIBRARY "${windows_LIBRARY} -L \"${linker_Path2}\"")
  endif()

  # Setting the Link Library Path in flag
  set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_C_FLAGS ${windows_LIBRARY})
  set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_CXX_FLAGS ${windows_LIBRARY})
  # setting the link library flag
  set(link_flags ${windows_LIBRARY})
  set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${link_flags} CACHE INTERNAL "exe link flags")
  set(CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS ${link_flags} CACHE INTERNAL "module link flags")
  set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS ${link_flags} CACHE INTERNAL "shared lnk flags")
endif()

set(_COMPILE_C "-c")
set(_COMPILE_CXX "-P -c")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH_FLAG "-L")
set(CMAKE_LINK_LIBRARY_FLAG "")
set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES "-bcc.lib" ".lib")

# uncomment these out to debug makefiles
#set(CMAKE_START_TEMP_FILE "")
#set(CMAKE_END_TEMP_FILE "")
#set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE 1)

# Borland cannot handle + in the file name, so mangle object file name
set (CMAKE_MANGLE_OBJECT_FILE_NAMES "ON")

# extra flags for a win32 exe
set(CMAKE_CREATE_WIN32_EXE "${_tW}" )
# extra flags for a console app
set(CMAKE_CREATE_CONSOLE_EXE "${_tC}" )

foreach(t EXE SHARED MODULE)
  string(APPEND CMAKE_${t}_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT " ${_tM} -lS:1048576 -lSc:4098 -lH:1048576 -lHc:8192 ")
  string(APPEND CMAKE_${t}_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT " -v")
  string(APPEND CMAKE_${t}_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO_INIT " -v")
endforeach()

# The Borland link tool does not support multiple concurrent
# invocations within a single working directory.
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_JOB_POOL_LINK)
  set(CMAKE_JOB_POOL_LINK BCC32LinkPool)
  get_property(_bccjp GLOBAL PROPERTY JOB_POOLS)
  if(NOT _bccjp MATCHES "BCC32LinkPool=")
    set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY JOB_POOLS BCC32LinkPool=1)
  endif()
  unset(_bccjp)
endif()

macro(__embarcadero_language lang)
  set(CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILE_OPTIONS_DLL "${_tD}" ) # Note: This variable is a ';' separated list
  set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_${lang}_FLAGS "${_tD}") # ... while this is a space separated string.
  set(CMAKE_${lang}_USE_RESPONSE_FILE_FOR_INCLUDES 1)

  # compile a source file into an object file
  # place <DEFINES> outside the response file because Borland refuses
  # to parse quotes from the response file.
  set(CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILE_OBJECT
    "<CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER> <DEFINES> <INCLUDES> <FLAGS> -o<OBJECT> ${_COMPILE_${lang}} <SOURCE>"
    )

  set(CMAKE_${lang}_LINK_EXECUTABLE
    "<CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER> -o<TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <FLAGS> ${CMAKE_START_TEMP_FILE} <LINK_LIBRARIES> <OBJECTS>${CMAKE_END_TEMP_FILE}"
    )

  # place <DEFINES> outside the response file because Borland refuses
  # to parse quotes from the response file.
  set(CMAKE_${lang}_CREATE_PREPROCESSED_SOURCE
    "${_EMBT_CPP_PREPROCESSOR} <DEFINES> <INCLUDES> <FLAGS> -o<PREPROCESSED_SOURCE> ${_COMPILE_${lang}} <SOURCE>"
    )

  # Create a module library.
  set(CMAKE_${lang}_CREATE_SHARED_MODULE
    "<CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER> ${_tD} ${CMAKE_START_TEMP_FILE}-o<TARGET> <LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_LIBRARIES> <OBJECTS>${CMAKE_END_TEMP_FILE}"
    )

  # Create an import library for another target.
  set(CMAKE_${lang}_CREATE_IMPORT_LIBRARY
    "implib -c -w <TARGET_IMPLIB> <TARGET>"
    )

  # Create a shared library.
  # First create a module and then its import library.
  set(CMAKE_${lang}_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY
    ${CMAKE_${lang}_CREATE_SHARED_MODULE}
    ${CMAKE_${lang}_CREATE_IMPORT_LIBRARY}
    )

  # create a static library
  if(BCC64)
    set(CMAKE_${lang}_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY
      "tlib64 ${CMAKE_START_TEMP_FILE}/p2048 <LINK_FLAGS> /a <TARGET_QUOTED> <OBJECTS>${CMAKE_END_TEMP_FILE}"
      )
  else()
    set(CMAKE_${lang}_CREATE_STATIC_LIBRARY
      "tlib ${CMAKE_START_TEMP_FILE}/p512 <LINK_FLAGS> /a <TARGET_QUOTED> <OBJECTS>${CMAKE_END_TEMP_FILE}"
      )
  endif()


  # Initial configuration flags.
  string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_INIT " ${_tM}")

  if(CLANG_BASED)
    string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT " -O0 -v")
    string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL_INIT " -O1 -DNDEBUG")
    string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT " -O2 -DNDEBUG")
    string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO_INIT " -O3")
  else()
    string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_DEBUG_INIT " -Od -v")
    string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL_INIT " -O1 -DNDEBUG")
    string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_RELEASE_INIT " -O2 -DNDEBUG")
    string(APPEND CMAKE_${lang}_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO_INIT " -Od")
    set(CMAKE_${lang}_STANDARD_LIBRARIES_INIT "import32.lib")
  endif()
endmacro()

macro(set_embt_target)
  foreach(arg IN ITEMS ${ARGN})
    if(${arg} STREQUAL "FMX")
      set(CMAKE_${_lang}_FLAGS "${CMAKE_${_lang}_FLAGS} ${_tF}")
      include_directories(SYSTEM "${ROOTDIR}/include/windows/fmx")
    elseif(${arg} STREQUAL "VCL")
      set(CMAKE_${_lang}_FLAGS "${CMAKE_${_lang}_FLAGS} ${_tV}")
      include_directories(SYSTEM "${ROOTDIR}/include/windows/vcl")
    elseif(${arg} STREQUAL "DR")
      set(CMAKE_${_lang}_FLAGS "${CMAKE_${_lang}_FLAGS} ${_tJ}")
    elseif(${arg} STREQUAL "DynamicRuntime")
      set(CMAKE_${_lang}_FLAGS "${CMAKE_${_lang}_FLAGS} ${_tR}")
    elseif(${arg} STREQUAL "Package")
      set(CMAKE_${_lang}_FLAGS "${CMAKE_${_lang}_FLAGS} ${_tP}")
    elseif(${arg} STREQUAL "Unicode")
      set(CMAKE_${_lang}_FLAGS "${CMAKE_${_lang}_FLAGS} ${_tU}")
    else()
      message("Error in set_embt_target: unknown target specified \"${arg}\"")
    endif()
  endforeach()
endmacro()
```

Anyone knowing how to configure CMake in order to be able to use these Embarcadero modified Clang compilers? This should be relevant for anyone using these compilers.

Comment: If Embarcadero's instructions and setup are not working for you, you should [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was trying to login to the page you suggested, however, getting I'm getting a "
Sorry, an error occurred trying to log you in - please try again.".. I will try later.

Comment: Tried again to login to file a bugreport.. -> that page keeps given the same error.. :(

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: I have two logins, when I tried my second one, I finally got in!! Don't get it why the other one don't work..? Well, time to file a bugreport..

Comment: Filed as an Embarcadero bugreport: RSP-20998

Answer (score 1):

The Cmake error shows that your compiler don't support some C++11 feature (nullptr or override).

I guess you can just comment the cmake code with "#". However you may encounter some compiler error when you ignore the C++11 feature's check.

Here list some method to Workaround for C++11 Attributes:

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Workaround_for_C%2B%2B11_Attributes_(Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers)

Comment: Hello Wei, I tried your suggestion and it allows me to compile vtk7 (with some code modifications). However, now I'm getting a linker error, related to the string class used by the clang distribution, see below.

Comment: I created a new question for this problem ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51690774/implement-derived-copy-and-move-constructor-for-stdstring)

Comment: "*The Cmake error shows that your compiler don't support some C++11 feature (nullptr or override)*" - the old BCC32 compiler is not a C++11 compiler. Only the newer BCC32C compiler is (as is BCC64, too). In which case, I find it odd that the Cmake file is not defining `set(CLANG_BASED TRUE)` for BCC32C, but does for BCC64

Answer (score 0):

Just get the clang executable file location, and the proper flags then put on CMake to:

`SET(CXX "/your clang c++ location")
add_definitions( special clang c++ flags )`